# Is it safe to delete from an array based state via array index?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-state

I just started with React and I am wondering if it is safe to delete via an array index or if this could end up with some kind of race conditions / timing issues. As concrete example, let's consider a table with 3 rows and in each row there's a *remove* button:

[image]

So my state contains:

```
first row  (index 0)
second row (index 1)
third row  (index 2)
```

Now the user deletes the second row, leaving us with this array content:

```
first row  (index 0)
third row  (now index 1 instead of 2)
```

Next, the user clicks on the third row before the component re-renders, so the remove button for the third row still references index 2 instead of already index 1. So `splice(index, 2)` is executed causing an error, because index 2 doesn't exist anymore.

Is that theoretically possible in React, if a user is lightning fast clicking the remove buttons?

**Sample code / Codesandbox**

Here's some concrete code example, which is also available on [my Github repository](https://github.com/wondering639/delete-by-index) and especially on [Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/delete-via-index-ctpes?file=/src/App.tsx)

**App.tsx (relevant code excerpt)**

```
<MyTable
  initialRows={[
    { id: 101, content: 'first row' },
    { id: 102, content: 'second row' },
    { id: 103, content: 'third row' }
  ]}
/>
```

**MyTable.tsx (relevant code excerpt)**

```
import { FC, useState } from 'react';

interface Row {
  id: number;
  content: string;
}

interface Props {
  initialRows: Row[];
}

export const MyTable: FC<Props> = function ({ initialRows }) {
  const [rows, setRows] = useState(initialRows);

  return (
    <table>
      <tbody>
        {rows.map((row, index) => (
          <tr key={`id${row.id}`}>
            <td>{row.content}</td>
            <td>
              <button
                type="button"
                onClick={() => {
                  const newRows = [...rows];
                  newRows.splice(index, 1);
                  setRows(newRows);
                }}
              >
                remove
              </button>
            </td>
          </tr>
        ))}
      </tbody>
    </table>
  );
};
```

Comment: “Index as a key is an anti-pattern” by Robin Pokorny : https://link.medium.com/Qlvf4n1D4bb

Comment: note that I don't use the index as key. I only use it for removal and want to know if that is safe or not (I know I would be safe by deleting by id instead of deleting by index, but I want to understand how (un)safe deleting by index is to better understand how state and re-renders etc relate)

Answer (score 0):

Your onClick handler should look something like this:

```js
onClick={() => setRows(rows.filter(elem => elem.id != row.id ))}
```

This is the best way to do it if you have an array of objects. In a real world application there should be an API call to change the data in the database first and if that is success, only then update the rows state using the filter method.

Answer (score 0):

No, this is not safe. A simple example to show why this is the case is as follows:

```js
const Component = () => {
    const [arrayState, setArrayState] = useState(['item 1', 'item 2', 'item 3'])

    const deleteItem = (index) => {
         const newArray = [...arrayState];
                  newArray.splice(index, 1);
                  setArrayState(newRows);
    }
    
    const deleteItemAfterSimulatedDelay = (index) => {
        // assume this simulates a slow network request
        setTimeout(() => {
            deleteItem(index)
        }, 300)
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        deleteItemAfterSimulatedDelay();
        deleteItem(index);
   }, [someOtherDependency])

}
```

Assume that `deleteItem` is the result of a quick network request, whereas `deleteItemAfterSimulatedDelay` is the result of a slow network request - this is obviously unrealistic but the results of network delays etc. could cause you to delete the incorrect item.

A better solution would be to filter the existing array per Amir's response, as even 'deleting by index' after finding that index is still subject to race conditions.

```js
const deleteByKey = (key) => {
    const itemIndex = array.find(item => {
        item.key === key
    })
    // this will guarantee that we're deleting an item with the correct credentials but is still subject to race.
    const deleteItem(itemIndex)
}
```